# How to rollback or commit multiple sql server stored procedures?

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, cakephp-2.0

I'm currently working on a proyect on cakephp 2.0 where i need to insert multiple users to a sql server database.

I need to make a rollback if something fails, but not necessarilly if the stored procedure failed, but if something within the php file logic fails throws an exception to make the rollback.

The code works like this:

```
try {
    ...$this->db->beginTransaction();//The connection to the DB is already on.
    foreach($users as $user){
        //some logic       

        if(something) {
            throw new Exception('blah blah');
        }

        $query = $this->sqlsrv->prepare('storedProcedure1');
        //bind parameters

        if(!$query->execute()) {
            throw new Exception('blah blah');
        }

        //some logic...

        if(something) {
            throw new Exception('blah blah');
        }

        $query = $this->sqlsrv->prepare('storedProcedure2');
        bind parameters

        if(!$query->execute()) {
            throw new Exception('blah blah');
        }    

    }
    $this->db->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    $this->db->rollBack();
}
```

I dont know if something like this may be possible, the functions return true, but the succesfull inserts from the stored procedures are still there, and i would like to tollback all of those even when they were succesfull.

Comment: are you using transaction commands inside the procedures?

Comment: I am not an expert on php but it looks to me that you are starting a transaction on one DB connection and then calling SPs from another connection (which does not have an active transaction).